# Determine whether it is homomorphism:

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine whether it is homomorphism:

$\phi: (\mathbb{Q}, \cdot) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \cdot)$, where

$\phi(x) =  \begin{cases}
      \sqrt x, & \text{if}\ x \geq 0 \\
      0, & \text{otherwise.}
    \end{cases} $

I have never seen this kind of problem, so thank you for helping.

Comment: Homomorphism in what sense? What structure is desired to be preserved? A topology? Algebraic operations? More? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to prove that
\phi(xy) = \sqrt(xy) is not equal to \sqrt(x) \sqrt(y)=\phi(x) \phi(y), so I think this is not a homomorphism.

Comment: I'm a little confused. The given structures are not groups under the notationally specified operation (multiplication), for the reason that in both structures, there is a $0$ element that does not have an inverse. They are both rings, which do have $0$ elements and a multiplication, but the notation specifies only the multiplication as the operation of interest, and square-rooting is notoriously ill-behaved with respect to addition, which might be another avenue. Can you give more context? Your approach seems to be leading somewhere. What happens in $\phi(xy)$ if $x$ and $y$ are both negative?

Comment: We are learning about algebras (algebra-like structures?!). 
So, if x and y are both negative, then ϕ(xy)= \sqrt(xy) = 0 and this equals to \sqrt(x) \sqrt(y)=\phi(x) \phi(y) = 0, I think and so when x and y are zero, right?

Comment: I was thinking about how $\phi(1) = \phi((-1)(-1))$ might not be $\phi(-1) \phi(-1)$. There's no $\sqrt{x}$ if $x$ is negative and the definition of $\phi$ does not require that. But products can turn negative things into positive things for which the rule determining what $\phi$ is changes

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As brought up in the comments to my answer, I shouldn't have mentioned the identity element at all. I've edited to remove that.

As discussed in the comments you would be well served by explicitly stating what sort of structure you want your homomorphism to preserve. Given that you write these as $(\mathbb Q, \cdot), (\mathbb R, \cdot)$ I will assume you mean to see if $\phi$ is a homomorphism of *semigroups*, i.e. it preserves the multiplication operation $\phi(xy) = \phi(x) \phi(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb Q$. Unfortunately, this condition fails. Consider indeed $\phi((-1)(-1)) = \phi(1) = \sqrt{1} = 1$. On the other hand, $\phi(-1) \phi(-1) = 0*0 = 0$. As $1 \neq 0$ in $\mathbb R$, $\phi((-1)(-1)) \neq \phi(-1) \phi(-1)$. Hence, $\phi$ is not a homomorphism of semigroups.

Comment: the OP mentions exactly one operation for each structure, the multiplication $\cdot$. So why it is unclear what should be proved? One has to show that the map is compatible with this operation. The neutral element  is a 0-ary operation. The OP did not mention this operation so there is nothing to prove about $\phi$ concerning the element $1$ and there is no reason to assume one has to prove that $\phi$ is an  homomorphism of monoids, It is no homomorphism because $\phi(a\cdot b)=\phi(a)\cdot \phi(b)$ does not hold  for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$, e.g. $\phi((-1)(-1)) =1\neq 0= \phi(-1) \phi(-1)$

Comment: It's perfectly clear to you and I sure, but OP said that they were unfamiliar with this sort of problem so I wanted them to think clearly about what exactly it means to prove something is a homomorphism. And yeah you're right that I should've said that $\phi$ should be a map of semigroups (or magmas if you will...) rather than of monoids, but since $\mathbb R - 0$ is a cancellation monoid under multiplication and $\phi$ is not identically $0$ I was conflating these types of homomorphisms implicitly. But you make a good point and I'll remove the $0$-ary operation from my answer.

Comment: I think it is not clear to you what it means to prove that something is a homomorphism. It is irrelevant that these structures are semigroups, too. The only thing that matters is that $\phi(a\cdot b)=\phi(a)\cdot \phi(b)$ for all $a,b$. Nothing else. If $\phi$ is compatible with the operation $\cdot$  then it is a homomorphisp, even if the operation is not associative. So for the structures $(\mathbb Q, -)$ and $(\mathbb R, -)$ the identity map $x \to x$ is a homomorphism, even if $(\mathbb Q, -)$ is not a semigroup because it is not associative.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware that you can define a general concept of a homomorphism in model theory or universal algebra as a set map that factors through the various $n$-ary symbols. So yes fine, I needn't mention semigroups or monoids but I chose to do so for pedagogical reasons, not for a lack of understanding. OP is new to this sort of thing and $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ have a myriad of structures you may want to preserve, so I wanted to remind OP that in this context a homomorphism only relates to this operation. I said semigroup/monoid instead of magma because magmas are less commonly known.